# e^x = 1 + x + x2/2! + x3/3! + x4/4! << e to the x power using java method

Tags: java

So. Hello smart ones. What am I doing wrong here? I just can't figure out what is wrong with this code. 10 points for whomever helps me.
I'm trying to use recursion to make a method for e^x. using the `e^x = 1 + x + x2/2! + x3/3! + x4/4! + ...` equation

```
public class tester {
    public static double power(double x, int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return x * power(x, n - 1);
        }

    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }

    public static double myexp(double x, int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (power(x, n) / factorial(n)) + myexp(x, n - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(myexp(x, n)); // unfortunately, increasing n value
                                            // makes it go infinite.
    }

}
```

So x is the x in e^x and n is the total value when up to nth term is added. So
for example, myexp(3,5) is going to be e^3 added up to 5th term.  Thus, the higher the n is, the more accurate e^3 is going to be.

Comment: "10 points for whomever helps me" What, you're not planning to accept an answer? No help from me then.

Comment: Each point carries how many dollars ?  ;)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." The code in the question doesn't compile, so can't be used to reproduce the problem described.

Comment: where is `x`and `n` coming from ?

Comment: For debugging purposes, I would add some more `System.out.print` so you can see what's going on. Then, I would try entering a very low number for `n`. After that, in order to help us help you, I would post all output.

Comment: why do have to do so much when you have Java Math class. It is as simple as Math.exp(n)

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I forgot to include the crucial detail, like x and n. I've just finished editing.

Comment: Well, Math.exp(n) method came from somewhere correct? Like from a scratch.  I'm trying to use some of the basic methods that I've made to create a e^x method.  Just for practice...It's like attempting to rebuild a mathematics formula.

Comment: arc676. I've already included comment(//) inside the code saying that as I increase the value of n, myexp() increases exponentially, indicating "infinity" after entering a certain value, as opposed to it's supposed to get closer and closer to the limit value of e^x

Comment: @user87902 yes, but you are implementing it in terms of `power` and `factorial`, at least one of which contains a bug: get these working first, then try building something which uses them like `exp`.

Comment: Andy Turner, could you indicate where in power or factorial that I have error in please?  I just can't spot it.

Comment: @user87902 see secolive's answer, and write tests.

Comment: 10 points to your level of Smartness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the "int" data type for the `factorial` method. More specifically, factorial numbers quickly become huge and the int data type is too small. For example, if you code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(factorial(50));
}
```

The output is 0 which is obviously wrong, hence your result of `Infinity`. Simply change the return type of factorial from `int`to `double` as follows:

```
public static double factorial(int n)
```

And then if you try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(myexp(1., 100));
}
```

You get `2.7182818284590455`

Comment: Any reason for `double` over something like `long`?

Comment: Well you have more headroom with double than with long because double can store much bigger values, although at some point you won't be very precise anyway.